# Create different orchestration with different receive location

Tags: http, biztalk, biztalk-2013, biztalk-orchestrations, receive-location

I need to have two orchestrations that take the same input schema message from an HTTP Receive Port.

The orchestrations do different things.

I do not understand how can I call either an orchestration or the other one.

I have just a solution in my mind but I don't think it right.

I create two different receive location. One orchestration -> One receive location..

It looks like the correct solution. But create a receive location mean create a virtual folder in my http site on IIS that contains the `BTSHTTPReceive.dll`.

So my doubt is: If I have 20 orchestration with same input, should I create 20 virtual folder that contain the DLL?

It looks an horrible solution.

What is the correct way to solve my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this a one-way or a two-way receive port/location?

In case of a one-way receive location, just promote properties and use basic content based routing (CBR) using publish/subcribe on your properties.

In case of a two-way receive location: which response will you be giving to your application?

Think of your orchestration as your web service. You need to take in the request and generate one response. How you deal with that request by forwarding it to N number of other orchestrations/applications is up to you, but publish/subscribe is built for this behavior.

Comment: It's a two-way receive location... 
Yes I am thinking the orchestration as a web service. But the web service has a url where it is deployed. For orchestration the url is given by the location. In each location I have to copy the `BTSHTTPReceive.dll`. This is strange to me, perhaps I'm wrong in something. 
I am new to biztalk, and company does not give me time to study it :( I think BizTalk is not a system I can work on without study.. I will try to see something about CBR. I've never header about that... Thank you

Comment: I found a very simple tutorial on content based routing here: https://psrathoud.wordpress.com/2013/11/22/simple-content-based-routing-using-send-receive-ports-in-biztalk/

It explains the basic concepts